# Spring 3 - Petclinic - ${owner.new} invalid expression in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat7

I have deployed the petclinic code from the SPring 3 svn samples repository in Tomcat7 and I get the following exception:

Internal error

> Root cause is: /WEB-INF/jsp/owners/form.jsp(4,1) "${owner.new}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: [new] is not a valid Java identifier org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/owners/form.jsp(4,1) "${owner.new}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: [new] is not a valid Java identifier

This expression resolves perfectly well in SpringSOurce tc Server Developer Edition 2.0.

Any ideas why Tomcat 7.0.2 has a problem with it?

Answer (score 4):

Bozho has ever reported this bug: [50147 - static is not a valid identifier](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50147).

It boils down to:

> The important part for this discussion is on page 21 (of the EL specification).
>
> ```
> Identifier ::= Java language identifier
> ```
>
> Java language identifier is defined by the Java Language Specification (JLS).

Identifiers are specified in [chapter 3.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#229286) of the JLS which indeed confirms that identifiers may not be a keyword.
As per the bug report, you need to access it as follows instead:

```
${owner['new']}
```

or

```
${owner.isNew()}
```

Answer (score 2):

The EL specification does not permit the use of Java keywords as identifiers. "new" is a Java keyword and hence ${owner.new} is not legal EL. Tomcat 7 enforces this rule by default (Tomcat 6 doesn't for backwards compatibility). The bug is in the Spring sample app.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the EL parser in Tomcat 7 is just a bit more strict than that in tcServer (which is based on Tomcat 6).

I suggest filing a bug at http://jira.springsource.org to that effect, it's almost certainly something they'll want to fix.

Comment: Whether Tomcat 7 EL parser is more strict or not, the class has an `isNew()` method, using `${owner.new}` is legal. I thus consider this as an EL *bug* in Tomcat 7. It's Tomcat that should get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It will work with `${owner.isNew()}` instead of `${owner.new}`.

Comment: This will indeed work that way, but that's **not** a bug in the EL parser of Tomcat 7. See also https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50147 (as linked in my answer on this question). One of Tomcat's developers, markt_asf, has also posted an answer on this question.