# Spring Petclinic: "${owner.new}" contains invalid expression(s), Tomcat (6.0.32)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat6

```
svn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/ petclinic
cd petclinic; mvn clean package
```

The `petclinic.war` deploys just fine to Tomcat (6.0.32), but when accessing the application, the styles are not displayed.

```
Root cause is: /WEB-INF/jsp/owners/form.jsp (line: 4, column: 1) 
"${owner.new}" contains invalid expression(s): 
javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${owner.new}]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/owners/form.jsp (line:4, column: 1) "${owner.new}" contains invalid expression(s):
javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${owner.new}] at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1218) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:870) at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:889) at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1790) at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217) at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353) at
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340) at
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644) at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358) at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
```

Is there anything extra that needs to be configured?

Comment: Perhaps including the offending line would help.

Comment: But how is this above error related to the styles? ("but when accessing the application, the styles are not displayed") - I don't see the relationship, it's a JSTL/EL error. The styles error should still exist in Tomcat6.0.32 / while in 6.0.29 it should work), referring to http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?110290-Newbie-PetClinic-questions and https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8422#comment-83336

Comment: btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879794/spring-3-petclinic-owner-new-invalid-expression-in-tomcat-7?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using this placeholder
`${owner['new']}`
?